# hibernate & integrity contraint violated

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

An app I'm working on is using Oracle and Hibernate as ORM. When I'm trying to insert PartyUserObject I keep getting following errors:

```
could not insert: [Person]; SQL [insert into PARTY (............)]; constraint [PARTY_FK1]
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PARTY_FK1) violated - parent key not found
```

The message seems to be obvious, but I can't configure Hibernate to get it working. 
Relevant entities' relations and hbm.xml files are as follows:

`PartyUser.java`

```
private Party ap;
```

`Party.java`

```
private Address address;
private Set<PartyUser> partyUsers;
```

`PartyUser.hbm.xml`

```
<many-to-one
            name="ap"
            column="AP_ID"
            class="Party"
            not-null="true"
            lazy="false"
            cascade="save-update,evict">
</many-to-one>
```

`Party.hbm.xml`

```
<set name="partyUsers" inverse="true" fetch="subselect">
    <key column="AP_ID"/>
    <one-to-many class="PartyUser"/>
</set>
```

PARTY_FK1 refers to address FK in the party table. As I said before save is called on the DAO for a newly instantiated PartyUser object (associated Party and Address objects are new as well). All ids are generated on the java side. As you probably noticed both entities has cascade turned on.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Do you have an entity `Person`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as to why this happens, but I see this error all the time. What I have been doing is at the beginning, when I add all of my data, first I turn off constraints with: `SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY FALSE` and then at the end I just turn it back on `SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY TRUE`. Not so much a fix, as it is a hack, but it works for us so I thought I would share the knowledge.

Comment: thanks for sharing, but it's a big production db and i guess such workaround won't be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, it turned out that hibernate was configured to use db sequence generation, but ids in turn were preassigned in the java code. fmdl